# How to create Quickbooks desktop and Salesforce integration? and need suggestions

Tags: quickbooks

I want to know about Quickbooks desktop and Salesforce integration.
I am going to make integration to send data from Quickbooks desktop to Salesforce.

This integration will send customer, Salesorders,invoices, items, credit from Quickbooks desktop to Salesforce.

I have a query about What if I will create Opportunity in Salesforce for Quickbooks desktop Salesorder and for Invoices? Is it good/correct what I am thinking?

Also how can I create credit from Quickbooks desktop into salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an in-house development effort or will you be using a connector? This link from Shellblack gives a very good [overview](https://www.shellblack.com/administration/options-for-syncing-salesforce-with-quickbooks/).

If you are using a connector, there are so many to choose [from](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=Quickbooks) with various price points and nuances.

These seem to be highly rated:

1. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q7fhEAA
2. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016bTHEAY
3. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000ptXmEAI

In addition to the integration connectors mentioned in the Shellback post, you can also check out [Jitterbit](https://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/quickbooks-integration/) and [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/quickbooks/salesforce/). I believe that using External Objects and [Salesforce Connect](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lightning_connect/lightning_connect_setup) is also a possibility but I assume this will be unnecessarily expensive, as this tends to run around USD 4,000 pcm.

If you are keen to do in-house development, then this link may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179052/salesforce-quickbooks-integration-using-rest-api.

My experience tells me that using a paid-for solution is often cheaper in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

We're one of the apps that Andy kindly linked to (we're Breadwinner) but we can't help the original poster as they want to integrate with QuickBooks (Desktop) and we only integrate with QuickBooks Online. Of the other links, DBSync definitely works with QB Desktop, and I'm not sure about the third.

You can also try Autofy, which integrates with QB Desktop.

The issue is that, whatever you pick, you'll need a program running on your Windows computer that can operate in the background. And, with that you get all the challenges of ensuring your own uptime.

If you do go with DBSync, read the reviews on the AppExchange carefully. Most are quite positive, though a significant percentage discuss unexpected  additional costs.

Finally, you can build a connection yourself, though this is no trivial task.